# Why doesn't solving for $x$ in $x^3=64a^3$ work in my way?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots

**1st way:**

$$x^3=64a^3$$

$$(x)^3=(4a)^3$$

$$x=4a\ (\text{Ans.})$$

**2nd way:**

$$x^3=64a^3$$

$$x^3-64a^3=0$$

$$[\text{Formula:}\ a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)]$$

$$(x-4a)(x^2+4ax+16a^2)=0$$

Roots of $(x^2+4ax+16a^2)$ aren't $4a$; they are imaginary. Why aren't the roots of $(x^2+4ax+16a^2)$ $4a$ and $4a$ as we expected them to be?

Comment: *"The roots of $(x^2+4ax+16a^2)$ aren't $4a$."* True. But they *do* satisfy $x^3=64a^3$. (Try it!) ... Your approach is like solving $x^2=9$ by observing $(x)^2=(3)^2$ and then asserting $x=3$. The observation shows that $x=3$ is *a* root, but it doesn't guarantee that $x=3$ is *the only* root.

Comment: In your first way, you are just substituting *a* root. You cannot say anything about its multiplicity. If you substitute $4a\omega^n$, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that $x^3=64a^3$ has (for $a\neq 0$) three roots, two of them complex. In your first way you just assert that $x^3=(4a)^3$ implies that $x=4a$, but if you allow complex $x$ then there are two other solutions. These other solutions, as you have determined, are the roots of the quadratic $$ x^2 + 4ax + 16a^2 = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your first way only works if you assume $x$ and $y$ to be real numbers. But note that

$$ y^3 = 1$$ for all three values $y = e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{6\pi i/3}, e^{6\pi i/3}$, therefore inferring $x = u$ from $x^3 = u^3$ is not true, that is it is only one possible solution. The general set of solutions would be

$$ x = e^{2\pi i/3}u, e^{6\pi i/3}u, e^{6\pi i/3}u$$.

(In your case $u =4a$.)